# Error Deploying Spring app to JBoss - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I have created a Spring webapp, the app is working on tomcat and CloudFoundry, but I am getting an error attempting to start the app on JBoss (OpenShift express).

On starting I get the following error:

```
2012/04/10 11:11:58,967 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)V
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:62) [org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:53) [org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:42) [org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
... 12 more
```

I assumed it was a JAR conflict/dupplication and went to check the maven setup for dependency conflicts, however, having checked the transitive dependencies in the Eclipse Maven Dependency heirarchy, I am definetly exlcuding all versions except 3.1.1 (this class in question was introduced in v3.0 i believe) - and that is of both `Spring-core` and `org.springframework.core`)

Anyone have any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I discovered the issue.

Using M2Eclipse Maven plugin in Eclipse, I had excluded the `spring-core` dependency (this had excluded the library from every dependency where it was a transitive dependency), I assumed this would be ok as I was using the `org.springframework.core` library instead.

However, it looks like it has only excluded them from the first level transitive dependencies, and in my built WAR file, it was still pulling down `spring-core.3.0.3` (I hadnt done this before as I am deploying to Redhat's OpenShift platform and it took a bit of work getting things set up so i could scp to the server to get the built war)

I have now fixed this issue by explicitly declaring a dependency on `spring-core.3.1.1` and excluding all others to ensure that the latest gets pulled down.

I guess the moral is don't believe the "Resolved Dependencies" view in M2Eclipse plugin for a view of the libs being used.